# How do I use the new css feature in Polymer?

Tags: html, css, polymer

I am trying to change the css on a paper-header-panel. According to the docs on Polymers website I can simple change the shadow with:

```
paper-header-panel {
  --paper-header-panel-shadow: {
      height: 6px;
      bottom: -6px;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 6px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  };
}
```

sadly I can't get it to work... I also tried to change the color on the paper-toolbar, it also does not work.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Polymer -->
<script src='bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js'></script>
<link rel='import' href='bower_components/polymer/polymer.html'>
<link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html'>
<link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html'>
<link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html'>

<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Test</title>

<style>
paper-header-panel {
  --paper-header-panel-shadow: {
      height: 6px;
      bottom: -6px;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 6px -3px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
  };
}
paper-toolbar {
  --paper-toolbar-background: green;
  --paper-toolbar-color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body class='fullbleed layout vertical'>
  <paper-header-panel class='flex'>
    <paper-toolbar>
      <div>Title</div>
    </paper-toolbar>
  </paper-header-panel>
</body>
</html>
```

Where do things go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason. I had to set my style as `is='custom-style'`.

```
<style is='custom-style'>
paper-header-panel {
  --paper-header-panel-shadow: {
      height: 6px;
      bottom: -6px;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 6px -3px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
  };
}
paper-toolbar {
  --paper-toolbar-background: green;
  --paper-toolbar-color: white;
}
</style>
```